# Compile error when connecting QTcpSocket::error() using the new Qt5 signal/slot mechanism

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, mingw, signals-slots

When I try to connect using the old signal/slot mechanism, it works fine, but it gives me a compile error using the new one:

```
// Old mechanism, this works:
connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(onError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
// Compile error when using the template version:
connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::error, this, &MainWindow::onError);
```

This is the error I get:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(QTcpSocket*&, , MainWindow*, void (MainWindow::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError))'
         connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::error, this, &MainWindow::onError);
                                                                       ^
```

My slot function:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void onError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError);
```

I found a [similar thread on Qt forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/24292/couldn-t-connect-to-qtcpsocket-error-with-the-new-signal-slot-syntax-in-qt5), and they say it's a bug in Qt but would be fixed by 5.1. My version is 5.4.2, however (using MinGW).

So is it a Qt bug for real, or is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right link to the Qt forums, but read the wrong part. Look for static_cast on this page.

```
connect (socket, static_cast<void (QTcpSocket::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)>(&QAbstractSocket::error), this, &MainWindow::onError);
```

This (not very elegant) cast is necessary because the method name "error" is ambiguous.

Comment: See also http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html#selecting-overloaded-signals-and-slots

Answer (score 1):

Your link is wrong, reason is that MOC compiler don't know with one should use.
If there are 2 same name signals but different params, MOC is confused with one you mean.

That why sometimes is better to use 'old' syntax than new one.

From [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket-members.html) you can find same function as good example of that:

```
error() const : SocketError
error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)
```

With one MOC should use? :)

Edit: I know that one of them is signal, other is normal function, but from MOC point of view, this don't matter, both are 'functions' from C++ point of view.
Only difference is 'generate c++ code from MOC' (as signals/slots are 'created by moc compiler')